# Unable to start rails (s command does not exist)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When ever I type `rails s`in command line in WINDOWS 7 then it gives me following output:

```
    Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                         # Default: C:/ror/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]              # Don't create a Gemfile
  -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                      # Skip .gitignore file
      [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                  # Skip source control .keep files
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]          # Skip Sprockets files
      [--skip-spring], [--no-skip-spring]                # Don't install Spring application preloader
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                              # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                         # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]                          # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                                         # Default: jquery
  -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--dev], [--no-dev]                                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge], [--no-edge]                              # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
      [--skip-turbolinks], [--no-skip-turbolinks]        # Skip turbolinks gem
  -T, [--skip-test-unit], [--no-skip-test-unit]          # Skip Test::Unit files
      [--rc=RC]                                          # Path to file containing extra configuration options for rails command
      [--no-rc], [--no-no-rc]                            # Skip loading of extra configuration options from .railsrc file

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]                    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]      # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip], [--no-skip]        # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help], [--no-help]        # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version], [--no-version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

As you can see s command does not exist and rails g scaffold doesn't work as well, it gives same output.

More info:
I have installed rails and ruby and devkit correctly with no errors.
I typed

```
rails new testproject
```

and it worked fine, the testproject was created successfully.
I just can't type rails s.

Comment: Did you change directories into the `testproject` folder before attempting `rails s`?

Comment: No I didn't do anything, I just typed rails new testproject, thats it.

Comment: Most rails/rake commands have to be executed inside of the root directory of your rails project. Try calling `cd testproject` and then any of the other commands.

Comment: thanks it worked but now its giving me sqlite error.. looks like i need to install that first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you run `rails new appname`, you need to `cd appname` before you can run `server`, `console`, etc. From your app root, you'll see a `bin/rails`, which is loaded when you're in your app directory and sets up all the app-specific commands via [Rails::Commands](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3e36db4406beea32772b1db1e9a16cc1e8aea14c/railties/lib/rails/commands.rb). To avoid the opposite problem you're having, it also cleverly disallows creating a Rails app inside your Rails app.